# images are showing a lot larger than actual image size on my div

Tags: jquery

I am showing images on divs. My actual image size are width: 300 and height: 300. When Open the actual image, it is small. But when I put the images in divs, on the browser, images are so big. I cannot figure out what setting to look at. I checked and verfied I am not changing the image size. Any ideas what I should check for. Is it possible to force the image size to be certain pixels in jquery?

this my code to display images on div:

```
$(function () { 
 $('#div1').html("").css({"border": "", "margin": "0"});
    var myImage6 = new Image(); 
    $(myImage6).load(function () 
    $("#div1").html(myImage6).css({"border": "2px solid #E0E0E0", "margin": "20px 20px 20px 0", "float": "top", "font-size": "12px"});


    }).attr('src', flowers_image).error(function(){
          $('#div1').html("").css({"border": "", "margin": "0"});
    })

    });
```

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can see what's happening?

Comment: Posting your code would help us help you.

Comment: do you have any .css that could be getting applied to your images?

Comment: Any luck applying the height and width, @user1471980?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to assign a height and width to the image.

```
$("#div1").html(myImage6).css({ "width": "300px", "height" : "300px", "border": "2px solid #E0E0E0", "margin": "20px 20px 20px 0", "float": "top", "font-size": "12px"});
```

After (or in the callback of) your .load method, add this line:

```
$( '#div1 img' ).css({ "width": "300px", "height" : "300px" });
```

Comment: that did not work, it just cuts of the image and font of the image are huge, not original.

Comment: Okay, there is another line you can add now. See updated answer in a minute.

Comment: thank you it worked. Do you have any idea why is this happening? Do you think my settings in ccs my be causing this?

Comment: Images will render at their native size, unless constrained by styling rules. The rule of thumb is that if your image isn't natively the correct size, add CSS height and width to your desired size.